# Group and Count in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

OK I might be asking a stupid question, but I'm banging my head over this..

Say I have a table like so:

```
FullName | DownloadDate
-------- | -----------------------
Jack     | 2012-03-21 00:00:00.000
Joe      | 2012-03-21 00:00:00.000
John     | 2012-03-22 00:00:00.000
```

I want to return the number of downloads by date so the resulting table is:

```
DownloadDate            | TotalDownloaded
------------------------| ---------------
2012-03-21 00:00:00.000 | 2
2012-03-22 00:00:00.000 | 1
```

How can I achieve this?

Also, you can assume that in my date column in the original data, I will always have a time of '00:00:00.000'.

Comment: What did you try? Post your SQL

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT DownloadDate, Count(DownloadDate) as TotalDownloaded
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY DownloadDate
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DownloadDate, COUNT(DownloadDate) [TotalDownloaded]
FROM TableName
GROUP BY DownloadDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql query:

```
SELECT DownloadDate,COUNT(FullName) AS TotalDownload
FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY DownloadDate
ORDER BY DownloadDate;
```

Comment: I posted this answer from my stackoverflow mobile app before... Thats why couldn't post in aligned manner...

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
SELECT DownloadDate, COUNT(1) as [TotalNoOfDownloads] 
FROM TableName GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: `GROUP BY 1` is not valid in SQL Server